# NextJS 14.0.3 - Uncaught (in promise) Error: NEXT_REDIRECT

Tags: reactjs, forms, redirect, next.js

I got a login page, that I need to redirect after login success to app section and app section that redirects to login if no user is logged.

The redirect in AuthGuard component works great:

```
import { PropsWithChildren, ReactNode } from "react";
import appState from "./zustand";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const AuthGuard = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren): ReactNode => {
    const user = appState((state) => state.User);
    if (!user) {
        // if user is not logged in, redirect to login page
        redirect("/user/login");
    }
    return children;
}

export default AuthGuard;
```

but I can't get rid of error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: NEXT_REDIRECT` in FormLogin component:

```
"use client"

import { login } from "@/utils/api/actions/user";
import appState from "@/utils/state/zustand";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { FormEventHandler } from "react";

const FormLogin = (): JSX.Element => {
    const handleLogin: FormEventHandler = async (e) => {
        // stop form from submitting
        e.preventDefault();

        // login logic...
        
        // login against backend
        const user = await login(...)

        if (user) {
            // set user in state
            appState.setState({ User: user });

            redirect("/app/")
        } else {
            // show error etc.
        }
    }

    return <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        //...
    </form>
}

export default FormLogin;
```

I searched internet, there are some issues with Next 13.x, but it tells that the redirect gives error, but redirects, so advice is to ignore the error.
In my case it doesn't do anything... It stays with current page.

Next.js v14.0.3

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by putting redirect into useEffect box listening to user state changes:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (user !== null){
            redirect("/app")
        }
    }, [user])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think nextjs calls redirect two times. Once in FormLogin second time in   redirect("/user/login"); Which causes it to freak out.

Try removing one redirect to fix error.

After that I suggest to keep all redirection logic inside auth-guard. And updating it's logic to make sure that it will be one redirect at a time.

```
if (!user) {
        // if user is not logged in, redirect to login page
        redirect("/user/login");
    } else if(user && justLoggedIn) {
       // If user just logged in redirect to app.
       redirect("/app");
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately putting all redirects to AuthGuard would need extra logic because AuthGuard is used on both Login page and App itself. So it would start ping-pong and fail :)

Comment: Not sure I follow regarding ping-pong and fail. In order to use auth guard you would need to remove redirect from form login. So that all redirects be controlled by auth-guard and it would be only one redirect at the time. However it seems you already found your answer.

Comment: Doesn't work anyway, because I can't use React hooks in server component (NextJS). Thanks for help

Comment: Understood. Although why does auth-guard have to be server component? Root layout should be server compoent. While auth guard is client component. Root layout is parent to auth guard component.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea... It's NextJS rules and errors and I don't have better exp with Next, until now I did only React or Next before server components...